# Fiction Author Fine Tuning Formula.

Tags: soft-question

I recently asked a question to find a formula for a fiction project.  I was met with a brilliant answer; but, I am missing key pieces of information to arrive at how the answer is wholly implemented.

[Fiction Author Searching For Formula.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1968841/fiction-author-searching-for-formula)

I would like to know how the constant representing the mouse (0.259) or wolf (5.021) was reached-so I would be able to alter a constant (likely the wolf) using a different animal, as to change the degree of scaling.

As an example, if we used a 4ft mouse and 12ft elephant as constants; how do I arrive at the 0.259 (mouse) and whatever number the elephant would be?  What was the mathematical process?

This way I would be able to convert any two animals into constants and have more control of the scale.

Comment: Tell us the weights of the mouse and the elephant, and then we can solve a system of equations (two equations with two unknowns) to figure out what $a$ and $b$ should be in your formula to make the heights come out as $4$ for the mouse and $12$ for the elephant.

Comment: The information is in the linked post.  

The mouse weighs 0.019kg and the elephant weighs 7,000kg.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the formula you want to use is $\text{height} = a + b \log(\text{weight})$.  Plugging in the height and weight of the mouse, we find that $4 = a + b \log(.019)$.  Plugging in the height and weight of the elephant, we find that $12 = a + b \log(7000)$.  So we have two linear equations for the two unknowns $a$ and $b$.  We can solve for $a$ and $b$ using algebra.

Comment: Can you walk me through solving them?  Please.  I understand we need to pick a variable to isolate in each-correct?  Then, substitute one solution as an unknown.  Finally, we isolate once more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to determine heights using the formula
$$
\text{height} = a + b \log(\text{weight}).
$$
Plugging in the height and weight of the mouse, we find that
$$
\tag{$\heartsuit$} 4 = a + b \log(.019).
$$
Plugging in the height and weight of the elephant, we find that
$$
\tag{$\spadesuit$}12 = a + b \log(7000).
$$
Now let's use equation ($\heartsuit$) to solve for $a$.  Subtracting $b \log(.019)$ from both sides of the equation, we find that
$$
\tag{$\clubsuit$}a = 4 - b \log(.019).
$$
Next, let's plug this value for $a$ into equation ($\spadesuit$).  This gives us
$$
12 = 4 - b \log(.019) + b \log(7000).
$$
Solving for $b$, we find that
$$
b = \frac{-8}{\log(.019) - \log(7000)} \approx .62417.
$$
Finally, plug this value for $b$ into equation ($\clubsuit$) to get $a$.

Comment: I think we solved it.  The unknown a ≈ 6.474 and b ≈ 0.624!  This plugged into the original formula gives both those heights.

Thank you, so very much!  :)